# kernel of the sum homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Given a finitely generated free abelian group $G$
and subgroups $K_1, \dots , K_r$
it is possible to describe easily the kernel of the homomorphism
$K_1 \oplus \dots \oplus K_r \to G$ given by $(k_1, \dots , k_r)\to k_1+\dots + k_r$.
It easy to see that if $r=2$ then the kernel is isomorphic to
$K_1 \cap K_2$. There exists such isomorphism in general?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe inductively consider the homomorphism $K_1\oplus\cdots\oplus K_{r-1} \to G/K_r$, figure out the kernel, and then lift it back to $K_1\oplus\cdots\oplus K_r \to G$? Could start by trying this for $r=3$....

Comment: Perhaps write $G$ as $\Bbb Z^n$, and the $K_i$ as matrices (corresponding to their images), then we can speak of algorithms.